# Merge two sorted arrays (leetcode 88): i cant understand how it wont go out of bounds

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, merge, indexoutofboundsexception

The solution I came across using two pointers:

```
var merge = function (nums1, m, nums2, n) {
    let idx1 = m - 1,
        idx2 = n - 1,
        idx3 = m + n - 1;
    while (idx2 >= 0) {
        nums1[idx3--] = nums1[idx1] > nums2[idx2] ? nums1[idx1--] : nums2[idx2--];
    }
};
```

The solution works but I can't understand this,

Consider `nums1 = [7,9,11,0,0,0,0], nums2 = [1,2,12,14]`,

at a point in the algorithm, the index for nums1 is at 7 and at 2 on nums2,

the next iteration will lead idx1 too be -1, what will happen at the comparison statement from then on?

(I hope I was able to make the question clear, please let me know if I need to put it in better words)

Comment: "*Consider nums1 = [7,9,11,0,0,0,0], nums2 = [1,2,12,14],*" what about the values of `m` and `n`?

Comment: `minimum reproducible example`

Comment: Also, OP, you could just paste your code into google chrome and use breakpoints to see what specifically will happen at any point in your code. You can use that to figure out `what will happen at the comparison statement from then on`.

Comment: `nums1[-1] === undefined` and `undefined` is not greater than any number. Therefor `idx2` will be decremented until it reaches `0` which then stops the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code can go out of bounds in 2 places, but it works fine, because Javascript is a little weird when it comes to out-of-bounds array accesses:

1. It can write new elements past the end of `nums1`.  Javascript will automatically lengthen the array to accommodate the new value.
2. It can compare `nums1[-1] > nums2[idx2]`.  `nums1[-1]` is `undefined`, so this comparison will always be `false`, which is exactly what the author wants.

If you ever write code like this, you should add comments explaining why it works, since it relies on peculiarities of Javascript that do not carry over into other languages and won't be obvious to everyone reading the code.

Comment: Thank you, i have a better understanding of it now.